# jsPlumb leaking memory when creating statemachine chart for 3000 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, memory-leaks, jsplumb

I am trying to generate flowchart using jsPlumb.

The instance.connect function works for less number of divs (jsPlumb windows), but when connecting 3000 divs the jsPlumb uses lot of memory and page crashes.

Is it leaking memory or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
<div class="demo statemachine-demo" id="statemachine-demo">
<div class="w jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" id="flowchartWindow1" style="top:10px">CBL  RMODE(ANY) OPT(STD) LIST LIB<div class="ep"></div></div>
.... so on
<div class="w jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" id="flowchartWindow3000" style="top:10px">CBL  RMODE(ANY) OPT(STD) LIST LIB<div class="ep"></div></div>
</div>

var instance;
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
    instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
        Endpoint : ["Dot", {radius:2}],
        HoverPaintStyle : {strokeStyle:"#1e8151", lineWidth:2 },
        ConnectionOverlays : [
            [ "Arrow", {location:1,id:"arrow",length:14,foldback:0.8}],/*[ "Label", { label:"FOO", id:"label", cssClass:"aLabel" }]*/],
        Container:"statemachine-demo"
    });
    var windows = jsPlumb.getSelector(".statemachine-demo .w");
    instance.draggable(windows);
    instance.bind("click", function(c) {
            instance.detach(c);
    });
    instance.bind("connection", function(info) {
        //info.connection.getOverlay("label").setLabel(info.connection.id);
    });
    instance.doWhileSuspended(function() {
        var isFilterSupported = instance.isDragFilterSupported();
        if (isFilterSupported) {
            instance.makeSource(windows, {
                filter:".ep",
                anchor:"Continuous",
                connector:[ "Straight" ],
                connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:"#5c96bc", lineWidth:2, outlineColor:"transparent", outlineWidth:4 },
            });
        }
        else {
            var eps = jsPlumb.getSelector(".ep");
            for (var i = 0; i < eps.length; i++) {
                var e = eps[i], p = e.parentNode;
                instance.makeSource(e, {
                    parent:p,
                    anchor:"Continuous",
                    connector:[ "Straight" ],
                    connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:"#5c96bc",lineWidth:2, outlineColor:"transparent", outlineWidth:4 },
                });
            }
        }
    });
    // initialise all '.w' elements as connection targets.
    instance.makeTarget(windows, {
        dropOptions:{ hoverClass:"dragHover" },
        anchor:"Continuous",
        allowLoopback:true,
        anchor:"Continuous"
    });
    var len = $('.w').length;
    for( var index=1; index < len; index++){
        instance.connect({ source:("flowchartWindow"+index), target:("flowchartWindow"+(index+1))});
    }
    len = null;
});
```

Comment: someplaces you're using `jsPlumb` and at others using the `instance` generated. Try using only jsPlumb and see if the issue is reproducible.

Comment: It didn't make any difference.I am using the statemachine demo script from github,the only difference is the number of divs and loop to connect all windows.

Comment: Google Chrome WebDev tools says Layout forced: jsPlumbUtil.extend.getSize under timeline tab there are large number of listeners.Memory Snapshot shows arrays are what causing the issues.I do not know if the arrays are some kind of reference data.Documentation doesn't mention if I could move this data to Java/PHP and lookup values using ajax.